# Creating space between two elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

Imagine me having an element created dynamicly each time this element is created there should be some sort of a check to make sure there is space between dyn created element and the element next to it

How would i make the browser automaticly realize that there should be a space between them?

```
    <ul class=dynamic elements>
            /*Dyanmic <li></li> created*/
 </ul>
<div id="test">elemetn2 </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what's not working right? Also we need to see your CSS. You can display that HTML in any number of ways, so we need to know what you're working with.

Comment: alright sorry ill edit the post @aaronburrows

Comment: Really not clear what the specific problem is. We have no idea what expected results should be

Comment: Basicly i want to expand the div and every element after it

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use a simple `margin` between the `li`?

```css
.dynamic-elements li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dynamic-elements">
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
<div id="test">elemetn2</div>
```